# Search Results Web Part - Hide pages based on Custom field

Tags: 2010, search, search-results

I have a Search Results Web Part (SRWP) and there are few Pages which are based on Content Type, that content type contains a field **"Visibility"**. There is a custom web part which searches for this content type pages and ignores the one's having Visibility set to false.

But since SRWP don't know about this field, it still shows up the one's having this field set to `false`.

Is there a way to customize SRWP to not show Pages where this custom field is set to false?

Or is there a way to completely ignore this content type in SRWP (since we have a separate page for searching these content types)?

Comment: please check this https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/pages/modify-the-search-refinement-panel-in-sharepoint-without-code.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the "Append text to Query" property on the Search Core Results webpart:

1. Search Core Results web part
2. Search Core Results Action Links
3. Results Query Options
4. Append Text to Query

Try to append something like `NOT YOURPROPERTY:1`

Hopefully this will give you all pages without your property, or with your property set to 0 (false)

http://maxderungs.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/using-append-text-to-query-in-search-core-results/

Comment: Do I need to create Managed Property first ? Also, can you please paste the XML/XSLT generated after setting the Append text to Query property.. I can't see the properties in UI, but have to work on XML/XSLT.. Or Web Part declaration..

Comment: Is `AppendedQuery=""` the property?

Comment: Could be, I do not have an environment at hand to configure this I'm afraid